# Максимальная синхронизации во времени выполнения приложениями команд полученных по сети

Tags: windows, c#, .net

Есть сервер, и клиенты двух типов: управляющая прога(user) из которой пользователь отправляет команды и программы(client) которые собственно эти команды выполняют. Решение должно гарантировать получение и выполнение команд client-ами. 
Чаще всего (практически всегда) каждый client стоит на отдельной машине. Все участники соединены в локальной сети, возможно что локальная сеть сделана специально под эти цели и лишних клиентов в ней нет. пользователь через user отправляет команду, ее принимает сервер и перенаправляет client-ам. Вот задача в том чтобы клиенты выполнили команду максимально синхронно во времени(максимальная допустимая разсинхронизация  40мс). Требования к минимизации времени через которое client-ы получат команду от user-а практически отсутствуют(1, 2, 3 секунды вполне допустимо) И еще, машины на которых стоят client-ы максимально сопоставимы по характеристикам (чаще всего это одинаковые ноутбуки выделенные для выполнения только этих команд) Язык разработки C#. 
Пока реализовал все выше перечисленное на основе System.Net.Sockets, все работает, но в 20% из 100% превышается максимально допустимый разсинхрон.
Думал научить сервер слать свое время по UDP client-ы постоянно будут синхронизировать с этим временем свои таймеры и сервер при отправки команды будет сообщать и время в которое необходимо эти команды выполнить, но вот нет совсем доверия к широковещательным рассылкам.
У кого какие мысли как это можно организовать? За ранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: если не секрет, для чего такая точность?

Comment: Интересная задача. 

Посмотрите на обсуждение подобной проблемы в одном из ответов на запрос: 

[синхронизация времени по сети](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/setup/4680804.all).

IMHO тут все упирается в определение задержки при доставке пакета.

Comment: Даже при обычном пинге средствами командной строки, задержа получения ответа всегда разная иногда в пределах 0-3мс, а иногда и все 300мс и не угадать когда ждать подвоха. Есть мысль: после коннекта client-а, сервер начинает слать свое время до тех пор пока ответ на это сообщение от clienta, вернется не познее определенного порогового значения. Как только это случилось, сервер прекращает спамить клиент и помечает соединение как доверенное. Таким образом время сервера и клиента минимально разное и можно отправлять команды с инструкцией их выполнить в определенный момент времени. Как вам?

Comment: Для чего такая точность к сожалению ответить не могу =) Описанную идею попробую и сообщу о результате.

Comment: думаю, нужно сделать свой локальный NTP сервер, что бы все часы в системе были синхронизированны. Это даст +-10 мс. Но есть ещё точность в переключении задач самой операционной системы. Она составляет от 15 до 130 мс.

Поэтому, теоретически можно будет выйти на 25-30 мс. Сервер, когда ставит задачу, просто указывает точное время, а клиенты делают корректную задержку, что бы начать исполнять в указанное время.

Comment: NTP сервер мне кажется для этой задачи не нужен, неужели я руками синхронизирую хуже) и ведь мне по сути не время нужно, а какой-то таймер с любым исчислением, нужно только обеспечить минимальную разницу этих таймеров. И все таки корректную задержку и время выполнения команды должен давать сервер, ибо клиенты не знают о существовании друг друга и решить какая задержка должна быть - не могут

Comment: я думаю, что ручками Вы сделаете хуже, иначе бы этого вопроса не задавали. NTP - это как по мне, идеальный способ обеспечить синхронность таймеров. Сервер смотрит на текущее время, знает, что отсылка команды - 10 секунд (с запасом) и выставляет время начала выполнения задачи. Клиенты получив задание, ждут эти 10 секунд (8-9, учитывая накладные расходы) и начинают исполнять задание.

Клиентам не нужно знать о друг-дружке. Ему сказали - начать выполнять в 19:00:00.010 - он и будет исполнять.

Comment: в локальной сети NTP даст погрешность всего 0.2мс, а не 10 или 20. и да NTP, работает поверх UDP.

Comment: @apal, а как вообще Вы меряете рассинхронизацию для разных машин? 

В смысле, почему Вы  уверены в точности этих измерений. По моему опыту измерение времени (продолжительности какого-либо процесса) даже на одном  компьютере обычно дает большой разброс.

Comment: Команды которые выполняют client-ы такие, что малейший разсинхрон можно увидеть невооружонным взглядом

Comment: Дааа уж... "Убедительно".

Кстати, Вы должно быть понимаете, что на клиенте постоянно происходят прерывания (как переодические от таймера, они обрабатываются диспечером ОС и могут вызывать переключение процессов, так и асинхронные, например от сетевой активности и т.п.), которые тоже могут влиять на исполнение уже запущенной команды.

Поэтому-то вопрос об измерении синхронности результатов совсем не прост.

Answer (score 1):

Пробовали использовать SignalR(я знаю что он на основе сокетов, но может он лучши использует их)? Он вроде постоянно держит открытым сокет, 
соотетственно поступают данные, идет оверхед по времени на обработку кода и отсылку по сети.